# Blocking specific user JWT tokens?

Tags: session, redis, jwt

Say a user logged in multiple times from different devices, and then they decide they want to logout of ***device a***, we have no way of deleting the ***JWT*** which was provided to that device right?

Here is what I've implemented, I'm not sure if this is how other sites do it or if it's a decent way of doing it.

1. User logs in
2. I create a redis session token, which has the userId + device name associated to it
3. I store this redis token as the subject of the ***JWT***
4. I pass back the ***JWT***.

Now that the user has a ***JWT***, they can now access secured api endpoints. Lets say the user wanted to remove this ***session***, here is what I've done.

1. User fetches * redis session tokens for the particular userId (of course they need a valid jwt to fetch this data)
2. They choose the ***redis session*** token which they want to destroy.
3. They send that token to a `/destroy/{token}` endpoint
4. The jwt which uses that has that token as the subject will not work anymore.

Doing it this way means on each request, I'll have to decompile the jwt, grab the redis token, and see if it still exists. I guess this isn't expensive todo at all using redis, or any other in memory DB.

Is this a solid/efficient way of doing this? Are there any better/easier ways of doing this?

Comment: With this setup, do you use a refresh token at all or only the JWT access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While implementing JWT authentication/authorization in several apps I also had this same question and reached the same solution if not a very similar one:

In my case, I would store the JWT + UserID + DeviceName in the database, and then I would have an HTTP Request 
`DELETE /logout/DeviceName` with a header `Authorization: JWTGoesHere`.

This gives me two benefits:

- I can now logout a user from any device using a valid JWT (it does not need to be exactly the same JWT, it only needs to be a JWT for *that* user).
- Makes possible the implementation of "Logout all sessions except this one".

In terms of speed, the applications we've developed receive hundreds of requests per second. 
More than 90% of these requests need to be authorized, which means checking that the JWT is syntactically valid, checking existence against the database and last but not least check if it's expired.

All these checks (using Redis as the database) take less than 10ms.

Bottom line is: Benchmark it, and if it doesn't take really long then it doesn't need any optimization.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good to hear that someone else is thinking the same way I am. So you haven't actually created a redis session token and stored it in the JWT, you've actually just stored the whole JWT in a redis cache, interesting. I was thinking of doing this, but came to a conclusion that using a session token and validating that for validity on each request would be give me a couple added benefits for free. Happy to list them in the question when I have time.

Comment: @Franco Thank you for sharing your approach, indeed it helps :) I am wondering though, how do you get the DeviceName (is it something like Computer, iPhone, etc.. or does it have anything extra besides the base string)? Does the device detection occur on the server side? What package do you recommend? Sorry for all the question, but this will help me and others :)

Comment: @franco Doesn't that contradict the purpose of a JWT? The whole point of using a JWT is that I can validate it without a server-roundtrip, and now that roundtrip is back in the game.
If I understand it correctly, your approach would work as well for an opaque token and is not specific for JWT.